# Logstash: Value too large to output

Tags: elasticsearch, jboss, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Recently built ELK stack using version 5.0.0-1

When groking a jboss log with 1 multiline filter, I'm seeing the following error:

```
[2016-11-14T19:48:48,802][ERROR][logstash.filters.grok    ] Error while attempting to check/cancel excessively long grok patterns {:message=>"Mutex relocking by same thread", :class=>"ThreadError", :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:90:in `lock'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:147:in `synchronize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-3.2.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok/timeout_enforcer.rb:38:in `stop_thread_groking'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-3.2.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok/timeout_enforcer.rb:53:in `cancel_timed_out!'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-3.2.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok/timeout_enforcer.rb:45:in `cancel_timed_out!'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-3.2.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok/timeout_enforcer.rb:44:in `cancel_timed_out!'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-3.2.3/lib/logstash/filters/grok/timeout_enforcer.rb:63:in `start!'"]}
[2016-11-14T19:48:48,802][WARN ][logstash.filters.grok    ] Timeout executing grok '%{DATA:prefixofMessage}<tXML>%{DATA:orderXML}</tXML>' against field 'message' with value 'Value too large to output (27191 bytes)! First 255 chars are: 2016-10-30 23:28:02,193 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.com.NAMESPACEREDACTED.NAMESPACEREDACTED.NAMESPACEREDACTED] (ajp-IPADDRESSREDACTED-PORTREDACTED-325) DEBUG  NAMEREDACTED | order xml ----------- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

This same filter worked just fine with 2.4, but now running the same filter on 5.0.0-1 I see this.

Has anyone seen this in this version of the ELK stack?

Comment: There's a similar open issue in the logstash grok repo: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/99

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/pull/98 . You can upgrade the plugin now, or you can wait for Logstash 5.0.1

Comment: I am using Logstash 5.0.1 and still receiving the grok timeout / value too large error  .

Comment: @ZianyD that may be because your regex is wrong. This error is supposed to happen for ReDoS regexps. In the case above this was an actual bug, but you haven't provided enough context to ascertain that.